# Break out of container div

Tags: html, css

I have the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/32qRC/

Where I have a `960px` wide container and two paragraphs that are contained within it.

I also have a div with a class of `full` that I want to break out of the container and fill the width of the browser window (note that I also have a body margin of 40px all the way around)

I have tried doing it using margin left and right `-100%` which half works, but makes the div much wider than I wanted it.

In short, if the browser is `1280px` wide, then full should become `1200px` wide (because of the 40px either side)

Any ideas?

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

    <div class="full"></div>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body
{
    margin: 40px;
}
.container
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: yellow;
}
.full
{
    background: red;
    height: 320px;
    margin: 40px 0;
    margin-left: -100%;
    margin-right: -100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not break out a parent element to make the child element grow full screen.

The best way is to close the content `<div>`, start the `.full` div and then start content again, as follow: http://jsfiddle.net/LKGwv/1/embedded/result/

```
.full
{
    background: red;
    height: 320px;
    margin: 40px 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

`position:absolute` will break your layout and make your div "float" over other elements inside content.

Comment: As it turns out I am actually able to edit the HTML for this so this works. In a previous version of the code, this wasn't possible hence the need for the negative margins etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Position `.full` absolute, so it won't have a relation to it's parent, but to the window. I don't know if you want to keep the 40px margin or not. If you want that change both `left` and `right` to 40px.

```
.full
{
    background: red;
    height: 320px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Check the [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/32qRC/2/) and the [fullscreen view](http://jsfiddle.net/32qRC/2/embedded/result/).

Comment: It's now overlapping the second paragraph.